# Invalid use of undefined type - C

Tags: c

Given the following:-

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "SOM.h"
int N = 10;
int FEATURES = 5;

struct _Node{
  int x, y;
  double w[];
};

struct Node **nodes;

void main(){
  init();
}

void init(){
  int i, j;
  Node tmp;
  nodes = malloc(N * sizeof(Node*));
  for(i=0; i<N; i++){
    nodes[i] = malloc(N * (2*sizeof(int) + FEATURES*sizeof(double)));
    for(j=0; j<N; j++){
      nodes[i][j]->x = i; //Troublesome line
      nodes[i][j]->y = j; //Troublesome line
      nodes[i][j]->w = {0.0, 0.1}; //Troublesome line
    }
  }
}

void clean(){
  //
}
```

And header:-

```
#ifndef SOM
#define SOM
typedef struct _Node Node;

void init();
void clean();

#endif
```

I am receiving the following at compile time:-

```
SOM.c: In function ‘init’:
SOM.c:25:7: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct Node’
SOM.c:25:15: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
SOM.c:26:7: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct Node’
SOM.c:26:15: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
SOM.c:27:7: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct Node’
SOM.c:27:15: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
SOM.c:27:24: error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
```

However, I have(to my knowledge) defined the _Node structure and given it the pseudonym Node. I think I am misunderstanding this error. Would somebody be able to explain what is wrong. I am not looking for a code fix per se, more an explanation of where I went wrong.

Regards

Comment: `struct _Node` is not `struct Node`...

Comment: Have you tried to declare your struct before your typedef? Otherwise it will not be known to the compiler, when your typedef is evaluted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
struct Node **nodes;
```

It needs to be either:

```
Node **nodes;
```

or:

```
struct _Node **nodes;
```

but not a mixture of the two, as you currently have it.